# Connecting to local Oracle Server via MacOS SQL Developer

Tags: oracle, installation

I am new to Oracle SQL, but I want to give it a shot and play around with the HR schema.
I don't want to use a VM, because I had a lot of issues with them.

Setup:
Oracle Server setup on WIN64 PC. HR and SYS works fine. (10.0.0.10 --> to understand later on)

Trying to connect via MacOS and SQL Developer (10.0.0.23).

On my Mac I am able to ping 10.0.0.10 and the other way around (10.0.0.10 (PC) to 10.0.0.23 (MAC)).

[Ping from Mac to Pc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ybfm.png)

So then I setup my listener (listener.ora) and my tnsnames.ora in the way oracle wants me to do (examples folder).

[Listener Setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2wcDJ.png)
[tnsnames setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/smDy9.png)

After this setup I rebooted the server.
Now I tried to connect as HR to my 10.0.0.10 machine.
(On my win pc I can connect and use HR and sys schema.)
[connectionHR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M01Jh.png)

After trying to connect, a "Testing connection" window opens and closes after 1 minute.

```
Status: No success: I/O-Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
```

Ive also tried to import the tnsnames.ora file and start from this file, but this wouldn't work either.

EDIT:
I updated my listener.

```
Anmeldung bei (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=localhost)(PORT=1521)))
STATUS des LISTENER
------------------------
Alias                     LISTENER
Version                   TNSLSNR for 64-bit Windows: Version 19.0.0.0.0 - Production
Startdatum                27-DEZ-2020 00:11:42
Uptime                    0 Tage 0 Std. 3 Min. 14 Sek.
Traceebene               off
Sicherheit                ON: Local OS Authentication
SNMP                      OFF
Parameterdatei des Listener C:\Users\Ben\Desktop\db_home\network\admin\listener.ora
Logdatei des Listener    D:\benOracle\diag\tnslsnr\DESKTOP-FT8E4S1\listener\alert\log.xml
Zusammenfassung Listening-Endpunkte...
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=127.0.0.1)(PORT=1521)))
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(PIPENAME=\\.\pipe\EXTPROC1521ipc)))
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcps)(HOST=DESKTOP-FT8E4S1)(PORT=5500))(Security=(my_wallet_directory=D:\BENORACLE\admin\orcl\xdb_wallet))(Presentation=HTTP)(Session=RAW))
Services ▄bersicht...
Dienst "52448234712340b69f274bcc790ecfe0" hat 1 Instanzen.
  Instanz "orcl", Status READY, hat 1 Handler f³r diesen Dienst...
Dienst "CLRExtProc" hat 1 Instanzen.
  Instanz "CLRExtProc", Status UNKNOWN, hat 1 Handler f³r diesen Dienst...
Dienst "cfc353defce0494a8a440e7d1f817c2d" hat 1 Instanzen.
  Instanz "orcl", Status READY, hat 1 Handler f³r diesen Dienst...
Dienst "orcl" hat 1 Instanzen.
  Instanz "orcl", Status READY, hat 1 Handler f³r diesen Dienst...
Dienst "orclXDB" hat 1 Instanzen.
  Instanz "orcl", Status READY, hat 1 Handler f³r diesen Dienst...
Dienst "orclpdb" hat 1 Instanzen.
  Instanz "orcl", Status READY, hat 1 Handler f³r diesen Dienst...
Der Befehl wurde erfolgreich ausgef³hrt.
```

`Host= Localhost`
Why is host still the local ?
--> This is in German. Comment if translation is needed.

[image: C:> netstat -a -b --> results]
[image: 2 listeners on the same port]

All connections on the port 1521:
[image]

Comment: I edited it, but it still throws an error.                    Listener refused the connection with the following error:
ORA-12514, TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor

Comment: On your DB server: `lsnrctl status`. Does it list your instance? You may need to connect locally and make sure you haven’t set `local_listener` to only register with a specific listener, but most likely you need to include a domain.

Comment: Normally, when I run this comman i get 8 Instances or more

Comment: I updated the question with the ```lsnrctl status``` output.

Comment: Stop the `listenermac` listener: `lsnrctl stop listenermac`. Remove it from the `listener.ora` and restart the main listener again.

Comment: I deleted the macListener. I tried several things out. I can only start the listener if `listener.ora` is set to localhost. If I try to start listener: ` TNS-12542: TNS: Adresse wird bereits verwendet
 TNS-12560: TNS: Fehler bei Protokolladapter
  TNS-00512: Adresse wird bereits verwendet
   64-bit Windows Error: 48: Unknown error`        --> Address already in use, translated. But this is the only file where i mentioned 10.0.0.10

Comment: That error means some other process is already listening on that ip and port, that’s why I said to stop the maclistener first. Check what you have listening on that port, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48198/how-can-you-find-out-which-process-is-listening-on-a-port-on-windows , if it’s the Oracle listener then it’s probably safe to assume it’s the old configuration that wasn’t stopped before you removed the config, so kill it and try again with the defaultly named listener.

Comment: You may also want to make sure that the firewall (if there is such a thing on windows) has port 1521 opened.

Comment: Other than that: "I don't want to use a VM, because I had a lot of issues with them". That is still the best way to use Oracle. I have been using a VM to run all versions of Oracle on my mac for 10 years.  You will find pre-build VMs here: https://www.oracle.com/downloads/developer-vm/community-downloads.html, including one with Oracle 19c pre-installed.

Comment: Another option if you do not want to run a full VM is to use a Docker image. See https://github.com/oracle/docker-images/tree/master/OracleDatabase/SingleInstance. Or just use one of the autonomous databases available with Oracle Cloud's free tier (https://www.oracle.com/cloud/free/)

Answer (score 1):

Your `listener.Ora` file is set to listen on localhost rather than your 10.0.0.10 ip. Change that, then restart the listener and make sure your instance is getting registered with it. Note that your `tnsnames.Ora` Isn’t involved here as you’re specifying everything in your sql developer connection, but you also need to correct the `host` there.